Export work package to PDF with comment from OpenProject
I want to export “activity” records (“comment” especially) from a singular work packge.
As far as I know from the official website, OpenProject is able to export an singular work with ”description”.
But I found an issue stated that an official forum member is also capable of exporting singular work package to pdf with “activity”. Which I didn’t find a way to make that happen.
I would like to know how to export work package to PDF with “activity”. Thanks.
I have tried all the export option in
"[a project]->...->Export"
and
"[a project]->Work packages->[a task]->...->Download PDF".
